# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in ReactJS Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi I am new to React and found out that we can use React by adding its required scripts in our main index.html file. So, I did all the required steps to add script and also made sure to include babel, because I am writing my main App in JSX. But an error from Babel keeps coming up 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' pointing to my import statement where I import React and ReactDOM.

Code files:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React-1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`App.js`

```
import { React, ReactDOM } from "react";
function Counter() {
  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(Counter);
```

Folder Structure:

-->`index.html`

-->`App.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import React when including it directly from a CDN.

```html
<script type="text/babel">
function Counter() {
  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Counter/>);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please explain why importing is not necessary?

Comment: @manusrao Because you're using the browser version of it, which provides React and ReactDOM as globals.